# How to change the color of a line using the div id

Tags: html, chartist.js

I have followed the docs of Chartist to have more than one chart on my page: (taken from https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html#as-simple-as-it-can-get )

```
<div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section" id="chart1"></div>
<div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section" id="chart2"></div>

<script>
  // Initialize a Line chart in the container with the ID chart1
  new Chartist.Line('#chart1', {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    series: [[100, 120, 180, 200]]
  });

  // Initialize a Line chart in the container with the ID chart2
  new Chartist.Bar('#chart2', {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    series: [[5, 2, 8, 3]]
  });
</script>
```

This works fine and I can easily add different charts from js by targetting the div id in my HTML.

However, I am having trouble changing the line/background colours of each of the charts.

So far I have tried:

```
<style>#chart1{stroke: white}</style>
```

in my HTML but it doens't do anything.

All of the examples I've seen define the css on a div class but I'm not sure how to apply that to this example

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this selector to override the line style on a given series

```
#chart1 .ct-series-a .ct-line {
  /* Set the colour of this series line */
  stroke: red;
  /* Control the thikness of your lines */
  stroke-width: 5px;
  /* Create a dashed line with a pattern */
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 20px;
}
```

For more visit [here](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html#styling-your-chart)

Comment: you should change the link to https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html#styling-your-chart